# How do i catch the CSSStyleDeclaration error in cssutils

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, error-handling

I'm having an issue catching the CSS property validation error detected by `cssutils.css.CSSStyleDeclaration`.

Initial Code:

```
from cssutils.css import CSSStyleDeclaration
invalid_css = 'color: bold-50;'        
invalid_style = CSSStyleDeclaration(cssText=invalid_css,validating=True)
```

Output:

`ERROR  Property: Invalid value for "CSS Level 2.1" property: bold-50 [1:1: color]`

I tried:

```
try:
    invalid_style = CSSStyleDeclaration(cssText=invalid,validating=True)
except:
    print('exception thrown....')
```

Output is the same and print statement does not run:

`ERROR  Property: Invalid value for "CSS Level 2.1" property: bold-50 [1:1: color]`

Next I tried:

I read the source code for `CSSStyleDeclaration` [here](https://bitbucket.org/cthedot/cssutils/src/3a01bd18118a6466ad93aa23caaa4164528b59ac/src/cssutils/css/cssstyledeclaration.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), but do not see what function even prints the error.

My goal is to catch, detect, or read this error; and output `True` if the style is valid or `False` if the style is not valid.

Comment: That doesn't look like a proper error.

Comment: You are right it turns out that is a logging system output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading more of the documentation I discovered that the `ERROR` message is output from the [logging system](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/docs/logging.html?highlight=log).

It turns out that `CSSStyleDeclaration` has a method `getProperty()` that returns a `cssutils.css.Property` object.

The `cssutils.css.Property` object in turns has a Boolean member named `valid`. Documented [here](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/docs/css.html#cssutils.css.Property.valid).

Solution use `Property` not `CSSStyleDeclaration`:

```
from cssutils.css import Property

property = Property(name='color', value='bold-50', priority='')
print(property.valid)

>> False
```